# SharePoint 2013 Calculating Scores

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

I am working in SharePoint 2013. I am trying evaluate the work of my staff and will be using a list to track this and want to assign a grade to the results. If the person gets a 4 out of 5 I want them to receive 80%.

The way I'm doing this is with a list that contains 5 questions with a drop down menu and the response are Yes, No, N/A. There is a second 5 columns that converts the drop down list selection to a 1, 0, or "Empty Record". Yes=1, No=0, N/A=Empty. This is an how I'm converting the responses to numbers: **=IF([Question1]="Yes",3,IF([Question1]="N/A"," ",0))**

So a response of (Yes, Yes, No, Yes, Yes) should convert to (1, 1, 0, 1, 1) which should = 4 out of 5. (80%)

The problem is how to calculate the grade so that if the an empty record doesn't factor into the calculation.

So a response of (Yes, Yes, No, Yes, N/A) should convert to (1, 1, 0, 1) which should = 3 out of 4. (75%)

I've got the conversion of the responses to numbers down pat, just can't get the calculation of the grade to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A True value is 1 and a False value is 0

So you can count the Yes strings (true) and the NOT N/A strings (number of Yes/No answers)

No need for any intermediate Calculations, all in one Column

```
=INT(AND(A1="Yes")+AND(A2="Yes")+AND(A3="Yes"))
 /
 INT(NOT(A1="N/A")+NOT(A2="N/A")+NOT(A3="N/A"))
 *100
```

for less typing you can leave out the *AND* and just write (A1="Yes") which returns True. You can not leave out the NOT because we want a NOT(false) = true value to count all non-N/A columns

Comment: I didn't use this exact formula but this put me in the correct mindset that let me accomplish what I needed. Thank you very much for the help!